# separate words in a sentence that has comma between them

Tags: python

I want to remove commas from one sentence and separate all the other words(a-z) and print them one by one.

```
a = input()
b=list(a)                      //to remove punctuations
for item in list(b):           //to prevent "index out of range" error. 
    for j in range(len(l)):
        if(item==','):
            b.remove(item)
            break
c="".join(b)                  //sentence without commas
c=c.split()
print(c)
```

My input is :

```
The university was founded as a standard academy,and developed to a university of technology by Habib Nafisi.
```

and when I remove the comma:

```
... founded as a standard academyand developed to a university...
```

and when I split the words:

```
The
university
.
.
.
academyand
.
.
.
```

what can I do to prevent this?
I already tried replace method and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split ) ?

Comment: @JimWright 
     "academy"
     "and"
separated

Comment: @janbrohl didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `,` with a space assuming there is no space between `,` and next word in your input <sup>1</sup> and then perform `split`:

```
s = 'The university was founded as a standard academy,and developed to a university of technology by Habib Nafisi.'

print(s.replace(',', ' ').split())
# ['The', 'university', 'was', 'founded', 'as', 'a', 'standard', 'academy', 'and', 'developed', 'to', 'a', 'university', 'of', 'technology', 'by', 'Habib', 'Nafisi.']
```

Alternatively, you could also try your hand at `regex`:

```
import re

s = 'The university was founded as a standard academy,and developed to a university of technology by Habib Nafisi.'

print(re.split(r' |,', s))
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>*Note*: This works even if you had space (multiple) after `,` because ultimately you `split` on whitespace.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be that there is no space between the comma and the next word here: `academy,and` You could solve this by ensuring that there is a space so when you use `b=list(a)` that function will actually separate each word into a different element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want, I see you forgot to `replace` comma with space.

```
stri = """ The university was founded as a standard academy,and developed to a university of technology by Habib Nafisi."""
stri.replace(",", " ")
print(stri.split())
```

Will give you the output in a list:

```
['The', 'university', 'was', 'founded', 'as', 'a', 'standard', 'academy,and', 'developed', 'to', 'a', 'university', 'of', 'technology', 'by', 'Habib', 'Nafisi.']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider words to be a series of characters that are separated by spaces, if you replace a , with nothing, then there will be no space between them, and it will consider it one word.

The easiest way to do this is to replace the comma with a space, and then split based on spaces:

```
my_string = "The university was founded as a standard academy,and developed to a university of technology by Habib Nafisi."
list_of_words = my_string.replace(",", " ").split()
```